# Excel - connect to a web API programatically with OfficeScript

Tags: javascript, excel, azure, api, rest

Is there a "Getting Started" tutorial for connecting an Excel workbook to a REST API using OfficeScript?

For querying / updating.

I can connect Excel on Windows to an Azure SQL Server via ADO and VBA. I realise that (these days) we should connect via an API, and with OfficeScript we should (?) be able to do this from any Excel (Windows, web) with OfficeScript. But I can't find any resources on this.

I'm not looking for direction on how to set up the API at this stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Office Scripts does not currently support importing other `JavaScript` libraries. It would be nice, but no. I found this while searching for similar functionality.

Please see here on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/javascript-objects#use-of-external-javascript-libraries-is-not-supported

EDIT:
Looks like there is some examples of getting data from a REST API after all. Check out this older link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/external-calls#working-with-fetch

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes I managed to get Excel on the web to consume a REST API with Fetch. I'll check the link also.